# WooCommerce Product Category hover effect

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hover, effect

is there a way to implement a custom CSS code, to give the products and categories a hover effect of "lift up" or "bump up" like in this example:

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/jolishop-harmonious-aesthetic-simple-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/19305276

I really like how it lifts up, and shows the border around it.

I have the effect in my avada but its only for images i place. I don't know how to do it so I can have the main shop page and all the products on a category page will do it as well...

I also tried downloading Woo Shop Hover Effects, but the closest they have to that effect is "pulse."

Answer (score 0):

To use custom CSS I recomend: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-awesome-css/
So it's just use some simple code like

```
.product { top: -1em; }
```

Adapt to your necessity

```
.product { bottom: -1em; }
.product { background: red; }
```

Comment: this did not work. this added a background to the individual product pages, but did not give any effect to the category and shop pages when hovered.